# Outlook - Send email without receiving new messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

I'm using Outlook 2013 via IMAP, and would like it to send emails immediately (or with a small delay), but only *receive* emails when I explicitly want to check for them.  I've tried Disabling Scheduled Send/Receive, but that doesn't seem to do anything.  Work Offline disables both send and receive.  Hitting F9 does a send *and* receive as well.

How can I tell Outlook to send but not receive?

(Note that I want to use the account for receiving as well, just only when I explicitly tell it to do so.)

Comment: If this feature exists in outlook 2013, I am unaware of it. I have never seen this setting or documentation for a workaround. But I definitely think it's interesting. So +1 for the question. Lets see if anyone can provide a useful answer.

Comment: It seems that Disabling Scheduled Send/Receive, or unchecking the boxes in the Send/Receive Groups, doesn't actually stop new messages from coming.  The only thing which does is Work Offline.

Answer (score 3):

Let's clarify what you meant with *I'm using Outlook 2013 via IMAP:*

- You are using Outlook 2013 to connect to an Exchange account via IMAP or IMAP-like protocol.
- You are using Outlook 2013 to connect to a non-Exchange account via IMAP.
- You are using another client, possibly in a mobile device, to connect to an Exchange account via IMAP or IMAP-like protocol.

For sanity's sake I will assume you meant the first one, though the second option will probably have the same behaviour with the first one *(I hope)*. For the third one, it might need another answer as mobile devices' behaviour might vary.

## Simple Answer

Before we go on, let me say that if you switched from IMAP to POP3, [then Adam Thomson's answer will be sufficient for you](https://superuser.com/questions/828556/outlook-send-email-without-receiving-new-messages#829038) :)

### Or would you rather read on...

[IMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) is supposed to work by syncing folders that you have subscribed (optionally: with *your own* custom filter) which is done ideally in near real-time. Outlook 2013 might have the tendency to guarantee this behaviour, ignoring the Send/Receive rules you may have set. But, Working Offline seems to break this behaviour *(or rather, Outlook's IMAP-syncing obeys the Work Offline's dictatorship)*.

If you are alright with switching to Work Offline mode *for eternity*, then please continue...

**Switch to Work Offline.** Done! Now we need a method to Send/Receive in offline mode. But only to send, not to receive.

Before you are too worried facing the doom of working offline forever *(or rejoice!--if your job is to answer those never-ending corporate emails)*, let me tell you that while working offline... you can still Send/Receive your emails! *(OH NO!!)*

Seriously, just **tick** `Include this group in send/receive (F9)` checkboxes in both Online and Offline category in the **Define Send/Receive Groups** settings window, also **tick** `Schedule an automatic send/receive every XX minutes` in both section, and also lowering the XX minutes to something lower, let's say `10 minutes` while you're at it. (Note that this is not actually the best use for these options.)

Now, have you defined *your own* Send/Receive Groups yet? No? Great! Click the **Edit** button! Yes, you say? You have set a custom group for your IMAP-enabled account? Doesn't matter! Select it, and then click the **Edit** button! Remember to check the other groups later, because *what matters most is on the inside*.

Inside, pick the email account you want *(if there is only one then it will be much much easier)*. Make sure you **tick** the main checkbox called `Include the selected account in this group`.

In the Account Options group box, **tick** `Send mail items` (so that you can send emails, *duh*), and **untick** `Receive mail items` (this is actually important). Untick other checkboxes as necessary.

Regarding those two checkboxes, let me add something mind-blogging for you a bit:

- You can still send mails with `Send mail items` option **unticked**, while offline, by issuing commands:

  - **Send/Receive All Folders (F9)** (if the group's Offline option `Include this group in send/receive (F9)` is **ticked**)
  - **Send All** (always)
  - **Update Folder** (when in the Outbox folder)
- You will still receive mails with `Receive mail items` option **unticked**, while offline, by issuing commands:

  - **Send/Receive All Folders (F9)** (if the group's Offline option `Include this group in send/receive (F9)` is **ticked**, and the group's `Include the selected account in this group` is **ticked** for the email account)
  - **Send/Receive (Inbox)** (always)
  - **Update Folder** (when in the Inbox or other incoming folders)

Just like what they said, *all roads lead to Rome*. But *Rome* here is actually what we don't want to reach. So what more can we do?

FEAR NOT! FOR THERE IS A SECRET I HAVE NOT TOLD YOU YET. SPOILER ALERT!!!

I have told you, *what matters most is on the inside.* QUICK! To that **Edit** button again!

Now you see, inside the inner Send/Receive group setting, in the Folder Options group box, there stand those shiny folders, ready for you to tick/untick. **UNTICK THEM ALL.** These tickmarks have been responsible for all of your grueling lifeless nights. They are the source of reason of why the Outlook IMAP demon behave like this. (Tick = sync folder. Untick = do not sync.)

## Let us summarize...

#### Disable folder auto-sync

1. Switch to **Work Offline**, and remain like this forever as necessary.
2. Open **Define Send/Receive Groups** options window.
3. **When Outlook is Offline:** tick `Include this group in send/receive (F9)`.
4. **When Outlook is Offline:** tick `Schedule an automatic send/receive every XX minutes` and other options as necessary.
5. Group item: Edit to open **Send/Receive Account Setting**.
6. Tick `Send mail items`.
7. Untick `Receive mail items` and other options as necessary.
8. Untick all folders if you don't want Outlook to auto-sync any of them.

#### Send emails

- **Send/Receive All Folders (F9)**.
- Or just wait if you have scheduled it to run even when working offline.

#### Check emails on demand

- **Send/Receive (Inbox)**.
- **Update Folder** (when in the Inbox or other incoming folders).

That's it. I hope it works for you.

Comment: This works great, *except* it also disables schedule availability lookup when scheduling a meeting.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this with [Send/Receive Groups](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Why-use-Send-Receive-groups-4da09253-6508-41a7-99e4-f5a4cb1d17ee) in Outlook 2013.

Click on the **Send/Receive** tab on the Outlook Ribbon.
Click on the **Send/Receive Groups** drop-down and select **Define Send/Receive Groups**.
Highlight the group you want to alter (eg *All Accounts*), and click on **Edit**.
Untick the **Receive mail items** checkbox, and click on OK.

That will prevent items from being received when the Send/Receive Group (eg *All Accounts*) is automatically scheduled to run. Now you need to create a new Send/Receive group for the same account, but one which will actually receive the messages.

You can do this by clicking on the **New** button, and making sure the **Receive mail items** checkbox is ticked. Click on **OK** when you have done this, and then highlight your new Send/Receive Group in the list.
Untick the **Schedule an automatic send/receive every ... minutes** checkbox, and the **Include this group in send/receive (f9)** checkbox.
Close the *Send/Receive settings* window, and from now on, only sending should happen automatically. You will need to manually select your new group from the Send/Receive Groups drop-down when you want to receive.

Comment: Can you test this with IMAP? I'm still getting new messages displaying, even after making your changes.